# iOS: UIButton Appearing, But Not Functioning On UIView

Tags: ios, swift

There are some similar questions out there on this, but they're in Obj-C and don't specifically answer my question.

I'm building a Tinder-like dating application with a button on the card that allows the current user to view more info about the user on the displayed card. I've written this button (moreInfoButton) programmatically and have it displayed on the card (UIView) without a problem. But when I click on the button, it does not function. I've tried isEnabled and isUserInteractionEnabled, but neither work. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class CardView: UIView {

var imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lady5c"))

var informationLabel = UILabel()

var images: [String]?

var userId: String?

var stackView: UIStackView?

let moreInfoButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "info_icon").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    return button
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    layer.cornerRadius = 15
    clipsToBounds = true

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.fillSuperview()

    addSubview(informationLabel)
    informationLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    informationLabel.anchor(top: nil, leading: leadingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16))
    informationLabel.text = ""
    informationLabel.textColor = .white
    informationLabel.layer.zPosition = 1

    addSubview(moreInfoButton)
    moreInfoButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 20), size: .init(width: 50, height: 50))
    moreInfoButton.layer.zPosition = 1
    moreInfoButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    // addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))

}
```

Comment: if you want whole the view can click, you should add `self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` in `init`

Comment: add action to your button

Answer (score 1):

if you add a button programmatically, I think you should use addTarget instead of using whole uiview gesture. This makes button has a functionality without having any relation about view gestures.

```
lazy var button: UIButton = {
    let temp = UIButton(type: .system)
    temp.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    temp.addTarget(self, action: someFunction, for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    return temp
}()
```

Comment: Thank you, but that still doesn't seem to work. This button, when tapped, is supposed to open a separate view controller containing the user's info (from the card). I forgot to mention that the UIView that displays the user's photo (upon which the button sits) is tappable so the current user can cycle through the user's photos (just like Tinder). Thus, when I tap the button, it recognizes it as in the "forward" half of the view and cycles to the next photo rather than executing the code for the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to share a drawing or something like that we can image for your exact needs ?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Since the button is sitting on top of the tappable view, make sure the button is displayed in front of the tappable view. If you are using storyboard, the button should be listed below the tappable view.

Also, in your touchesBegan method, make sure you don't respond to touches inside your button:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if touch?.view != button && touch?.view == tappableView {
        // Next picture
    }
}
```

If that still doesn't work, try this implementation of touchesBegan instead:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    if touch?.view == button {
        // performSegue or call button's target function
    } else if touch?.view == tappableView {
        // Next picture
    }
}
```

---

You are missing a target for your button:

```
moreInfoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and a function to handle the tap:

```
@objc func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    // action
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that still doesn't seem to work. This button, when tapped, is supposed to open a separate view controller containing the user's info (from the card). I forgot to mention that the UIView that displays the user's photo (upon which the button sits) is tappable so the current user can cycle through the user's photos (just like Tinder). Thus, when I tap the button, it recognizes it as in the "forward" half of the view and cycles to the next photo rather than executing the code for the button. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think UITapGestureRecognizer conflict with button tap event.
You can try use override touchesBegan event instead of tap gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Disable `cancelsTouchesInView` property of the gesture. By default, I think it is set to `true`. This means that the gesture consumes the touch event and it is not passed on to the button

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```